# Inapp Purchase : Can we add bunch of products in itunes connect dynamically?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I have one Application,in that i need to add around 100 products for Inapp Purchase I know all the procedure doing manually one by one but do we have any other way to do add these many products in a bunch dynamically?

May be via some xls format file etc.

So can any one help me to find feasible solution.

Thanks.

Comment: did you mean, you could be able to dynamically add products without changing/uploading new build ?

Comment: No, before upload build add product detail in bunch of products.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello I have find the solution so you can add multiple products from application loader

So open you application loader application (if not then down load it) then follow the bellow steps.

Application loader >> Create new package >> New from file

OR you can follow this [Link](http://www.pixeldock.com/blog/how-to-add-a-large-amount-of-in-app-purchase-items-to-itunesconnect/) for further detail.

Also check on this reference [Link](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/UsingApplicationLoader.pdf) (Creating Your In-App Purchase section) document for more info.

Answer (score 2):

You could use Transporter, Apple’s command-line tool used for sending App Store packages (.itmsp) to the App Store.

Check out **App Metadata Specification** and the **Transporter User Guide** in the footer of iTunesConnect's *Manage Your Apps* section.

[image]

Although I never used it, I also found [this](https://github.com/colinhumber/itunes_transporter_generator) github project which seems to kinda simplify the required xml generation.

Comment: I vaguely remember if you use the SDK from parse.com there is some way to make this easier.